# Automate GNU-Screen session creation via script

Tags: bash, jupyter-notebook, conda, gnu-screen

I've got the following command do work (using a ubuntu ec2 instance):

```
screen -dmS SESSION_NAME && (screen -S SESSION_NAME -p 0 \
    -X stuff 'source activate CONDA_ENV\n jupyter notebook\n')
```

This creates a detached `GNU screen` session and passes the command to activate a Python Conda environment (`source activate CONDA_ENV`) then starts the Jupyter Notebook webserver (`jupyter notebook`).

But I couldn't get it to work inside a bash script to automate this process.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Is your $PATH different in the script than on your login shell ?

Comment: @ivanivan as far as I know, it is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be `stuff`ing too early so the first `screen` command may have not finished the initialization work. So wait a little while before `stuff`. Like:

```
screen -dmS SESS && {
  sleep 2;
  screen -S SESS -X -p 0 stuff 'something\r';
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That sure was quick @pynexj :)